# Verifying USB-C voltage

Tags: usb

I have heard about some USB-C chargers frying tablets, phones, etc. If I ordered a generic charger online for price reasons, how can I can verify its voltage before using it with my Android devices?

Comment: DC voltmeter can help. You can't measure using Android device. Better to stick to reputed charging brands-generic ones can cause a lot of trouble

Comment: To clarify, you can measure on the device but not a good idea if the charger is suspect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists an Android app for this purpose called "USBCheck":
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jacob.uk.com.usbcheck

Unfortunately it is currently only supporting Nexus 5X and Nexus 6P.